# mpOpenAPI is not discovering my resources

Tags: openapi, open-liberty

Running Open Liberty 18.0.0.3 with mpOpenAPI-1.0 and some JAX-RS resources.

The Resources is working, and the http://localhost:9080/openapi/ui/ is also running, but noone of mye JAX-RS resources is displaying in the OpenAPI gui

The doc stated that it should not be neccesary with any addition annotation, but even though I tried like this:

```
@Slf4j
@Path(value="/")
@RequestScoped
public class DomaResource {


    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Operation(
                summary = "Get All Maps",
                description = "Retrieving all the available maps at the destination"
              )

    public MapInfo[] getAllMaps() {
..
..
```

Am I missing something else ?

The plain output from 'http://localhost:9080/openapi' is :

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Deployed APIs
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: http://localhost:9080/doma
```

/bwa

Comment: Are there any error messages in your console?  Are you using web.xml or a subclass of javax.ws.rs.Application to configure JAX-RS?

Comment: No errors, have tried both web.xml and Application

`@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class DomaApplication extends Application{
 
}`

The resource is working perfect, it's the openapi which is not finding the resources.

Answer (score -1):

You can open issue here:
https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues

It would be helpful if you could provide information about if there are any errors in logs/ffdc folder

Comment: Well, before I open a issue, I would like to confirm that I have done it the right way?